# What's wrong in my code??? Update query not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm posting this question after debugging it several times. Please have a look.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["g"]) && isset($_POST["c"]))
{
    $g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['g']);
    $c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
    //echo $g.$c.$log_username;
    if($g == "" || $c == "")
    {
        echo "The form submission is missing values.";
        exit();  
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET gender='$g',country='$c' WHERE username='$log_username'";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
        //echo $query;
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        //echo $numrows;
        if($numrows > 0)
        {
            echo "success";
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "failed";
            exit();
        }
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

The error i'm getting is 
`Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sns2\root\account_config.php on line 36`

I'm perfectly getting the values of `$g,$c,$log_username` (tested it using echo). I'm being connected to the database. I don't think there is something wrong with the query syntax because I have manually executed the same query using the values of `$g,$c,$log_username`. The query was executed. So could be wrong in this?? Please help!!

Comment: Where are you setting `$db_conx`?

Comment: in a file called check_login_status.php and it is included in my page.

Comment: I'm getting connected to db. I tested it.

Comment: Just because you're using `mysqli` it doesn't mean you're safe from trivial SQL injection attacks. Use prepared statements.

Comment: side note: The values of `$g` and `$c` are _probably_ safe for usage as string literals in an SQL query; is the same true for `$log_username`? In case of doubt see http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string and http://php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements

Comment: @VolkerK I'm sure that the same is true for $log_username.

Answer (score 1):

Citing the php documentation for `mysqli_query`:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful **SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN** queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object.
>   For **other successful queries** mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So you're probably getting a `TRUE` return value and should use http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php instead

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_affected_rows in case of UPDATE queries.

Comment: what is the exact syntax of mysqli_affected_rows??

Comment: Now i'm not getting any error but the control is bypassing the if block and entering else and returning me failed.

Comment: Maybe `echo "<pre>failed: |", htmlentities($sql), '|</pre>';` will give you a clue. ( and don't forget to remove that output afterwards ;-) )